# Comparing two lists using "for in range(0,7,1)"

Tags: python

I want to compare two lists and for each element place the lowest one first.
Here is my code:

```
l1=[1,14,26,37,100,86,77]
l2=[2,13,27,38,99,85,78]
newlist=[]

for elementnr in range(0,7,1):
    if l1<=l2:
        newlist.append(l1[elementnr])
        newlist.append(l2[elementnr])

    else:
        if l1>=2:
            newlist.append(l2[elementnr])
            newlist.append(l1[elementnr])
print(newlist)
```

Desired output is a new list with the comparisons:

```
newlist[1,2,13,14,26,27,37,38,99,100,85,86,77,78]
```

only comparing two and two numbers, not the whole lists.

The problem with my code is this newlist compares the first two numbers but then it keeps adding from l1 first then l2 through the entire list, instead of doing new comparisons.

Thanks in advance (this is practice a for possible exam task, that's why I can't use min/max/sort functions etc.)

Comment: Maybe I see it wrong, but the comparison if L1 <= L2 looks wrong to me. Shouldn't this be: if L1[elementnr] <= L2[elementnr] ?
And shouldn't else: if L1 > 2 just be something like  else:   ? because there is no feasible third option?

Comment: Yes, it works now, had to remove the l1>=l2 from the else, and then added l1[elementnr]<=l2[elementnr] in the if sentence, now it works perfectly, thanks so much for the help, been stuck on this shit for god knows how many hours!!

Answer (score 2):

You should compare

```
if l1[elementnr] <= l2[elementnr] ...
```

not

```
if l1<=l2:
```

When you're comparing two lists, python does element-wise comparison. Which means that your `l1` will always be "lower" that `l2`

Comment: I've tried this, but then i get the error: line 21, in <module>
    l1[elementnr]>=2[elementnr]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's some artifact of older/other code. If you see such error, please provide full code snippet with it

Comment: ye, turns out it was the l1[elementnr]>=l2[elementnr] in the else sentence that was screwing up the program, now the if  l1[elementnr]<=l2[elementnr] sentence works, thanks for the help, it's most appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

You always compare the whole lists, not the individual elements.

You could do:

```
if l1[elementnr] <= l2[elementnr]
```

but it's more Pythonic to iterate through the lists together, via `zip`:

```
for l1_elem, l2_elem in zip(l1, l2):
    if l1_elem <= l2_elem:
        newlist.append(l1_elem)
        newlist.append(l2_elem)

    else:
        newlist.append(l2_elem)
        newlist.append(l1_elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your title says 'using “for in range(0,7,1)”', so I hope this isn't unwelcome. But it's a pretty unpythonic pattern. If you would  use `zip` instead and something like `for l1, l2 in zip(l1, l2):` it will be easier to read and reduce the likelihood that you make the kind or errors you are experiencing.

For example:

```
l1=[1,14,26,37,100,86,77]
l2=[2,13,27,38,99,85,78]
newlist=[]

for l1, l2 in zip(l1, l2):
    if l1<=l2:
        newlist.append(l1)
        newlist.append(l2)
    else:
        newlist.append(l2)
        newlist.append(l1)
print(newlist)
```

You also might like exploring [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html) where you can use chain for something like:

```
from itertools import chain
l1=[1,14,26,37,100,86,77]
l2=[2,13,27,38,99,85,78]

l3 = chain(*sorted(zip(l1, l2)))
print(list(l3))
```

Comment: Ye, the thing is, my course uses python but the course is called BasicProgramming, so we're not alowed to use the python specific commands, but i always appreciate tips :)

Comment: I see, @Darmo, hopefully you'll be on to regular `for … in` in a few days.